# Set Google Analytics custom dimension using _gaq.push()

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to set a GA's custom dimension in my code. I know the most straightforward way to do it would be:

```
ga("set", "dimension1", "1");
```

However, I don't have access to `ga()` where I want to set this dimension. As a result, I tried the following lines:

```
_gaq.push(["_set", "dimension1", "1"]);
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "dimension1", "1"]);
```

The first one doesn't work at all, and the second one sets a custom variable, not a custom dimension.
I cannot find any reference to an hypothetical `_setCustomDimension()` function in [GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration), and nothing about dimensions in [ga.js](http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js) either.

Is there a solution to that?

Comment: I've been in the exact same situation today, and you tried the exact same things as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There are no custom dimensions in ga.js, you need to switch your property to Universal Analytics (or use custom variables instead).

I admit it's a bit confusing that alle versions of Google Analytics use the same user interface - there are some menu items that apply only to certain versions (or certain setups for certain versions).

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "or use custom dimensions instead". Isn't that what I am already doing?

Comment: @PierreEspenan I am sure Eike meant custom variables (I took a liberty to edit this in his answer), which are available in Google Analytics. Custom dimensions can be used only if you use Universal Analytics (see this page for more details: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450662?hl=en)

Comment: @PetrHavlík, yes, indeed - thank your correcting that mistake.